# PHP Header called by json

Tags: php, json, header

I am having an problem with this script, the header redirect is not getting called but the MySQL query does.

It looks weird to me as the MySQL query get called and the header does not?

PHP Script which should redirect:

```
if (array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ) {

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    if (!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)) {
        exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
    }   

    // Move the uploaded file from the temporary 
    // directory to the uploads folder:

    if (move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$key.'-'.$pic['name'])) {
        $name = $key.'-'.$pic['name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `uploads` (id, file_name, up_date, rm_date) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$up_date', '$rm_date')"; 
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // **Get called**
    header("Location: download.php?id=$id"); // **Does not get called**
    exit();

    }

}
```

And Javascript which calls the PHP script

```
$(function(){

    var dropbox = $('#dropbox'),
        message = $('.message', dropbox);

    dropbox.filedrop({
        // The name of the $_FILES entry:
        paramname:'pic',

        maxfiles: 1,
        maxfilesize: 25,
        url: 'upload.php',

        uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
            $.data(file).addClass('done');
            // response is the JSON object that upload.php returns
        },

        error: function(err, file) {
            switch(err) {
                case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                    showMessage('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                    break;
                case 'TooManyFiles':
                    alert('Too many files! Only one at same time is allowed.');
                    break;
                case 'FileTooLarge':
                    alert(file.name+' is too large! Please upload files up to 25mb.');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        },

        // Called before each upload is started
        beforeEach: function(file) {
            if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)) {
                alert('Only images are allowed!');

                // Returning false will cause the
                // file to be rejected
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are uploading with `AJAX` then it should not redirect.

Comment: This http://pastebin.com/yyfddgD5 is the full script, also I am using jQuery.filedrop.js

Comment: How can you say that the header is not called? Because you have an error with your Mysql query or what? - Okay, not working = not a question. Unless you can not provide anything with substance next to your code I'll vote to close.

Comment: With header is not called I meant that it wont redirect

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you wish to redirect the calling client to another page? Well, you have to do that via JavaScript here, acting on the response you receive from the server. Since your browser doesn't actually *"go"* to the page you're requesting via JS, the rewritten Headers do not influence the Location of your client.

you can use

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
```

to redirect via JavaScript.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do not use bare `window.location`. It is an object, it has properties (`href`) and methods (`replace()`) that can be used to redirect with js.

Comment: I tried both and they are not working

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Thank you! I actually failed to realize that.

KelvinCobanaj: So it's just not redirecting? That is rather strange. Can you repost your code with the redirect built in?